# No gps icon with Google Play Services

Tags: android, geolocation

Is it normal that the default android gps icon doesn't appear in status bar when determining user's location using `Google Play Services`, and why it's not shown, if so? It can seem a little bit confusing to user, because, AFAIK, this icon appears each time some app tries to determine user's location. Can it be related with `Fused Location Provider` - f.e., not showing the icon when using only wi-fi?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The icon indicates GPS usage. If the fuse location provider decides to not use it, you won't see it.